# JS/Jquery button handler for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i am doing a website for a personal project, and i am stuck.
I have a page with a list of products, and each one have its own button that when it be clicked it must link to another page where the user can read more information about the product.
This second page it's fixed for all the products with same layout.
So how can i make to each button to send to this page and tell him to load the information for the specified product?
for example imagine Amazon, you have the list of products and when you click on one of them, you are resend to the page of the product to read all the informations about it; and all the products have the same page, only the information about the specified product that you are whatching are changed.
here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
       <?php 
           include ("top.php");
           include ("common.php");
           include ("projects/get_projects.php");    
       ?>
       <link href="style/explore.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script4.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <?php include ("nav.php");?>
       <div id = "container"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

here what i made in js (i load the data with ajax)

```js
const data =  [{
    "username": "User1",
    "title": "Applicazione android per gestire le lezioni",
    "descr": "Mi serve una semplice app android per gestire dei corsi universitari. Per maggiori informazioni mandatemi un messaggio",
    "budget": "250\u20ac - 750\u20ac",
    "category": "app",
    "data": "2020-02-25",
    "flag": "Non disponibile"
  },
  {
    "username": "User2",
    "title": "Software per gestire i pagamenti in cassa",
    "descr": "Mi serve un software da installare all'interno dei computer alla cassa di un supermercato per poter gestire i pagamanti. \r\nDeve offrire la possibilit\u00e0 di cancellare un prodotto, inserirne uno manualmente, consentire il pagamento in contanti o col pos, etc.",
    "budget": "1500\u20ac - 3000\u20ac",
    "category": "software",
    "data": "2020-04-16",
    "flag": "Disponibile"
  },
  {
    "username": "User3",
    "title": "Configurazione rete aziendale",
    "descr": "Mi serve un esperto in sistemi per installare una rete aziendale protetta.",
    "budget": "+ 5000\u20ac",
    "category": "sistemi",
    "data": "2020-04-16",
    "flag": "Disponibile"
  },
  {
    "username": "User14",
    "title": "sito web per impresa di costruzioni edili",
    "descr": "Mi serve un semplice sito su cui pubblicare tutte le foto dei miei lavori e permetterei ai clienti di contattarmi facilmente via email.",
    "budget": "250\u20ac - 750\u20ac",
    "category": "web",
    "data": "2020-03-25",
    "flag": "Disponibile"
  },
  {
    "username": "User5",
    "title": "Database per azienda di catering",
    "descr": "Mi servirebbe un database per gestire un'azienda di catering.\r\nAll'interno andrebbero inseriti dati di ricette, men\u00f9, cuochi, eventi, personale, etc.\r\nBisogna inoltre dotarlo di tutte le funzioni per aggiungere o aggiornare tale elenco",
    "budget": "250\u20ac - 750\u20ac",
    "category": "database",
    "data": "2020-04-16",
    "flag": "Disponibile"
  },
  {
    "username": "User6",
    "title": "Mi serve un esperto per fare un video musicale",
    "descr": "Sto per far uscire il mio nuovo pezzo musicale e devo realizzare il video della canzone per poterla postare su YouTube.\r\nMi serve quindi un esperto che sappia montare un video in modo professionale.",
    "budget": "3000\u20ac - 5000\u20ac",
    "category": "altro",
    "data": "2020-04-16",
    "flag": "Disponibile"
  }
]


function showInfo(data) {
  var htmlString = "";
  var containerPrj = document.getElementById("container");

  if (data.length == 0) {
    htmlString = "<span id = " + "message>" + "Non è stato trovato alcun progetto" + "</span>";
    containerPrj.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
  } else {

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      htmlString = "<div class = " + "project>" +
        "<span>" + data[i].username + "</span>" +
        data[i].title + " | " +
        data[i].category + " | " +
        data[i].budget + " | " +
        data[i].data + " | " +
        data[i].flag + " | " +
        "<button id =" + "details>" + "Dettagli" + "</button>" +
        //each of this button must link to a page where i can see more information about this specified button that represent 1 specified product
        '</div>';
      containerPrj.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
    }
  }
}

 showInfo(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please click edit. Then click `[<>]` snippet editor. Get rid of all PHP and create a [mcve] using an EXAMPLE JSON and ONLY enough JS to show the issue. No need to show PHP or Ajax if that part works. Also why `containerPrj.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);` when you have jQuery

Comment: To do this you can send the `id` of the item to be shown in the next page in the URL where it can either be read on the server side (preferred option) or client side JS.

Comment: mmm ok @RoryMcCrossan but how can i code this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = [{ "username": "User1", "title": "Applicazione android per gestire le lezioni", "descr": "Mi serve una semplice app android per gestire dei corsi universitari. Per maggiori informazioni mandatemi un messaggio", "budget": "250\u20ac - 750\u20ac", "category": "app", "data": "2020-02-25", "flag": "Non disponibile" }, { "username": "User2", "title": "Software per gestire i pagamenti in cassa", "descr": "Mi serve un software da installare all'interno dei computer alla cassa di un supermercato per poter gestire i pagamanti. \r\nDeve offrire la possibilit\u00e0 di cancellare un prodotto, inserirne uno manualmente, consentire il pagamento in contanti o col pos, etc.", "budget": "1500\u20ac - 3000\u20ac", "category": "software", "data": "2020-04-16", "flag": "Disponibile" }, { "username": "User3", "title": "Configurazione rete aziendale", "descr": "Mi serve un esperto in sistemi per installare una rete aziendale protetta.", "budget": "+ 5000\u20ac", "category": "sistemi", "data": "2020-04-16", "flag": "Disponibile" }, { "username": "User14", "title": "sito web per impresa di costruzioni edili", "descr": "Mi serve un semplice sito su cui pubblicare tutte le foto dei miei lavori e permetterei ai clienti di contattarmi facilmente via email.", "budget": "250\u20ac - 750\u20ac", "category": "web", "data": "2020-03-25", "flag": "Disponibile" }, { "username": "User5", "title": "Database per azienda di catering", "descr": "Mi servirebbe un database per gestire un'azienda di catering.\r\nAll'interno andrebbero inseriti dati di ricette, men\u00f9, cuochi, eventi, personale, etc.\r\nBisogna inoltre dotarlo di tutte le funzioni per aggiungere o aggiornare tale elenco", "budget": "250\u20ac - 750\u20ac", "category": "database", "data": "2020-04-16", "flag": "Disponibile" }, { "username": "User6", "title": "Mi serve un esperto per fare un video musicale", "descr": "Sto per far uscire il mio nuovo pezzo musicale e devo realizzare il video della canzone per poterla postare su YouTube.\r\nMi serve quindi un esperto che sappia montare un video in modo professionale.", "budget": "3000\u20ac - 5000\u20ac", "category": "altro", "data": "2020-04-16", "flag": "Disponibile" } ]


function showInfo(data) {
  let html = [];
  const $containerPrj = $("#container");

  if (data.length == 0) {
    $containerPrj.html('<span id="message">Non è stato trovato alcun progetto</span>')
    return;
  }
  data.forEach(function(ele) {
    html.push('<div class="project">')
    html.push('<span>' + ele.username + '</span>');
    html.push(ele.title + " | " + ele.category + " | " + ele.budget + " | " + ele.data + " | " + ele.flag + " | ");
    html.push('<button class="details" data-username="'+ele.username+'">Dettagli</button>');
    html.push('</div>');
  })
  $containerPrj.append(html.join(""))
}
$("#container").on("click",".details",function() {
  // this could be ajax too !
  console.log($(this).data("username"));
  // or window.open("newpage.html?username="+$(this).data("username"))
})

showInfo(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: but with this code i don't open a new page for the selected button

Comment: That part you need to decide how to do. Change `console.log($(this).data("username"));` to `window.open("newpage.html?username="+$(this).data("username"))`